# Add one image to all products

Tags: magento-1.9

How can I (quickly) add one image to all products in my Magento (1.9) store? This Image needs to go at the end (in addition to existing images).

Comment: Do you want to view that image in product detail page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Below code :

```
     <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '600M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin'); 
$ImagePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/yourImage.png';
$products_model =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array("eq" => 1))
                ->load();  
foreach ($products_model as $pid){
    $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid->getId()); 
    $productModel->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()))
                 ->addImageToMediaGallery($ImagePath,'', false, false) 
    $productModel->save();
}
?>
```

You need to save this file on your root folder and run it through url like:
Save it `addimage.php`  then run it `www.yoursite.com/addimage.php`